# Detect from server side if user has not installed/trusted my private CA in his computer

Tags: c, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

I'm developing a server application that must first try using TLS/SSL for secure communication through network, but if some problem happens to achieve it, should fallback to plaintext, not encrypted, communication.

This application will use certificates generated through my own private Certification Authority (self-signed certificates), so by "some problem" I mean the case where user has not yet installed/trusted my CA in his computer and so client application may warn it (like browsers do) of insecure connection.

I would like to know from you if there is some way to know by the use of OpenSSL (or some easy to use alternative TLS/SSL implementation library) C API if user has not installed/trusted my private CA on his side, so I can fallback to plaintext communication even before client application bothers it with warning messages. I can't rely on client side verifications as my application is intended to be compatible with third party clients. Is it possible?

**EDIT:** I just want to know if it's possible to detect from server side if user has installed/trusted on my private CA in his computer. If possible, what should I check for with OpenSSL on my server application?

Comment: @jww Your edit rejected. Incomprehensible. OpenSSL is specifically mentioned in the question, and HTTPS is not.

Comment: @EJP - I'd love to hear how this has something to do with OpenSSL (other than the OP happens to know the library name), but I've got other things to do today. Good luck with it.

Comment: @jww It's your edit. You justify it. Tell us where you got HTTPS from, and how the OP's mention of OpenSSL isn't relevant. I should hope you have better things to do than make incorrect edits.

Comment: @jww Who is Olaf? And in what way was/is it broken? You have not answered that, despite being asked several times.

Comment: @EJP - I left the reason in the reason block. Enjoy the question; its some of your finest work.

Comment: @jww Your reason is incomprehensiblefor the reasons *I* stated. I asked for an explanation, which you have not furnished. Still no information on Olaf either. Mystery continues.

Comment: @EJP - If you would have asked before the revert, I would have been happy to help. Since you have taken ownership and performed the re-tagging, nothing more needs to be explained. The mystery will continue. You will figure it out eventually.

Answer (score -1):

> I mean the case where user has not yet installed CA certificate in his computer and so client application will fail doing TLS/SSL handshake

There is no such case. No certificate from the client in response to a `CertificateRequest` is not a TLS error and does not cause a handshake failure.

What really happens is that the handshake succeeds, and when the server *application* goes to get the peer certificates it doesn't get any. What form this takes in OpenSSL I do not know. But you have to write code for it.

**EDIT** As it now appears you are talking about missing *server* certificates, your question doesn't really make sense. One of the steps in initializing OpenSSL is telling it where to find the server private key and certificate, and by this stage you can surely tell whether it is present or not. Meanwhile what exactly is the client supposed to do? Try an SSL handshake and continue via plaintext if it fails? Start in plaintext and somehow magically be told to use TLS?

Comment: So the side effect of client receiving an invalid (signed by an untrusted CA) certificate from server is not providing any certificate for server when it requests for one? That makes no sense for me, except if certificate client provides when requested is the same server has previously sent, but will only be provided if it can be verified through a CA. Is this what happens?

Comment: @Tiago.SR It doesn't make any sense to me either, and it isn't what I said. Read what I wrote again. I specifically said 'No certificate from the *client*'. It also doesn't appear to be what you're asking about, although it isn't all that clear.

Comment: I just want to know if it's possible and how to do from server side, if user has installed/trusted on my self-signed CA at his computer. If it didn't installed/trusted, so I will continue in plaintext.

Comment: So you need to try an SSL handshake and see if it succeeds.